# How to get Attributee in laravel collective?

Tags: php, laravel

I installed `composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.2.0"`

I have a selection with some options and I'm using Laravel Collective Forms to build it, I have something like:

```
{!! Form::select(
    'user_id',
    \Modules\User\Entities\User::pluck('full_name',
    'id')->toArray(),
    old('user_id', $report->complainant_id),
    ['class' => 'form-control','id' => 'user_id',
    'placeholder' => 'First & Last name',]
) !!}
```

User.php

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
}
```

I see this error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'full_name' in 'field list'

Comment: How about `\Modules\User\Entities\User::all()->pluck('full_name','id')->toArray()`